# How to do groupBy, filter, and count together in Underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, linq, underscore.js

As far as I search, in `Underscore.js`, we can use `groupBy` function. Here is the syntax:

```
_.groupBy(list, iteratee, [context])
```

For example, we do: `_.groupBy(['one', 'two', 'three'], 'length');`

Then, the result is: `{3: ["one", "two"], 5: ["three"]}`

As you can see, the result contains 2 sets. **Now, what I want is: get the criteria used for grouping, and total number of elements in each set.**

So, the result should be: `{3: 2, 5: 1}`. Because set `3` has 2 elements, and set `5` has 1 element.

I can easily do this in LINQ using `Select` and `Count`. But I have no idea how to do this in `Underscore.js`.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`_.countBy` method](http://underscorejs.org/#countBy):

```
_.countBy(['one', 'two', 'three'], 'length');
// {3: 2, 5: 1}
```

From the docs, this matches what you're trying to achieve:

> Sorts a list into groups and returns a count for the number of objects
>   in each group. Similar to groupBy, but instead of returning a list of
>   values, returns a count for the number of values in that group.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, this should work:

```
_.each(
  _.groupBy(['one','two','three'],'length'),
  function(x,y,z){
    z[y]=x.length;
  }
);
```

Comment: `_.groupBy` returns an object, instead of `Array`. So `map` will not work.

Comment: Oh whoops. Sorry, will fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`_.mapObject()`](http://underscorejs.org/#mapObject).

```
var grouped = _.groupBy(['one', 'two', 'three'], 'length');
var result = _.mapObject(grouped, function(items) {
  return items.length;
}); // {3: 2, 5: 1}
```